# How to pass NSManagedObjectContext to view controllers when using storyboard (iOS)

Tags: ios, core-data, uitabbarcontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am using a `tab bar controller` in conjunction with `core data`. Each of the different tabs needs to have access to the `NSManagedObjectContext`, however I do not want to use a singleton or just pull them off the `app delegate`. Is there a way to pass them to the view controller programmatically from the `app delegate` when the app loads?

Comment: Just add a property `managedObjectContext` to each view controller and set the value when creating the tab bar controller, e.g. in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Comment: Thanks - since I am using a storyboard I dont manually create the VC's though. They are already created...

Comment: OK, but if you have an outlet to the tab bar controller then you can access its `viewControllers` and set the property for each view controller. - (I am not sure if that is better than pulling them from the app delegate ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a tab based app in a storyboard the rootViewController of the window will be the `UITabBarController`. From there you can get the viewControllers that make your tabs.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UIViewController *firstVC = tabBarController.viewControllers[0];
    firstVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    UIViewController *secondVC = tabBarController.viewControllers[1];
    secondVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    // more...
}
```